# How to access JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

How do i get "LSZ09".

```
var el1=data[0];
alert(el1);
```

This gives me "a" from array, as position 1 gives me r, 2 r, 3 a, 4y ,..

The array is received through a " echo json_encode($punten); "

Also when i try

```
var jsonDataArray = JSON.parse(data);
```

I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

Code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'getPunten.php',
                        data: {statnam: jSelectedStation[0]},
                        type: 'get',
                        success: function(data) {
```

Received from php script, with last line being: echo json_encode($punten);

```
[{"STATDEV":"LSZ09 ","0":"LSZ09 ","DEVPKT":"1","1":"1","PKTTYP":"S","2":"S","KARTNR":"0","3":"0","BITNRK":"1","4":"1","BITSTATUS":"0","5":"0","TYPE":"I ","6":"I "},{"STATDEV":"LSZ10 ","0":"LSZ10 ","DEVPKT":"1","1":"1","PKTTYP":"S","2":"S","KARTNR":"0","3":"0","BITNRK":"2","4":"2","BITSTATUS":"0","5":"0","TYPE":"I ","6":"I "}
```

php:

```
$db = new PDO ("xxxx");
$qry="SELECT r.refnam, r.zustnr FROM refdev r INNER JOIN (SELECT refnam, COUNT(*) cnt FROM refdev rc GROUP BY refnam) rc ON rc.refnam = r.refnam LEFT OUTER JOIN texte t ON r.sigtnr = t.textnr WHERE rc.cnt = $aantal AND t.tstring LIKE '%$tekst%' ORDER BY r.refnam, r.zustnr";
$filterQry = $db->query($qry);
$filtered = $filterQry->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($filtered);
```

Comment: That whole dump of the array isn't actually part of your code is it?

Comment: Also, show your PHP and javascript separate

Comment: @Jonathon Henderson nope it isn't it is received from a php script

Comment: Think you 're getting confused. The last chunk of code you're giving us is the output from something like `print_r` or `var_dump`, not `json_encode`

Comment: Show us your PHP, it looks like it's outputting malformed JSON, which is why you're getting a syntax error when trying to parse it

Comment: added it at the bottom

Comment: Remove your `var_dump` from the PHP. What happens then when you access the PHP file directly? What output do you get?

Comment: You're injecting SQL into your code. It doesn't help using PDO if you're still injecting SQL and making your code incredibly insecure. Use prepared statements and bound variables.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Not sure what u mean with injecting, but there will be no security problems as this will be a local website used for 1-2 persons

Comment: @PHPnooblet Imagine if `$tekst` was `' OR 1 = 1 --`. Then it would return every single row in the database, because you don't use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that php you've shown is the one you're using,no, it won't work.

You see, the text that gets passed to the javascript includes the results of *both* `var_dump` and `echo`.

Consider the following php code:

```
<?php
    $filtered = array(1,2,3);
    var_dump($filtered);
    echo json_encode($filtered);    
?>
```

What do you think the result of this is? Hint: it's not what you've been expecting.
You seem to be expecting it to be

```
 [1,2,3]
```

Well, it is - at least in part. That's the output of the last line only. But we've not considered the middle line `var_dump($filtered);` - the code that will output something similar to the code you've labelled with *`Received from php script, with last line being: echo json_encode($punten);`*

The output of my snippet is actually:

**`array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }`** `[1,2,3]`

That's why you're getting the first 5 elements containing 'a' 'r' 'r' 'a' 'y'!!
Its also why the call to `JSON.parse(data);` fails - `"arrray(3)"` isn't valid json.

Hint: when you navigate to the php script with a browser, what you see there is what will be retrieved with an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, removed var_dump and now i'm getting:
[{"STATDEV":"LSZ09 ","0":"LSZ09 ","DEVPKT":"1","1":"1","PKTTYP":"S","2":"S","KARTNR":"0","3":"0","BITNRK":"1","4":"1","BITSTATUS":"0","5":"0","TYPE":"I ","6":"I "},{"STATDEV":"LSZ10 ","0":"LSZ10 ","DEVPKT":"1","1":"1","PKTTYP":"S","2":"S","KARTNR":"0","3":"0","BITNRK":"2","4":"2","BITSTATUS":"0","5":"0","TYPE":"I ","6":"I "}
-
**How to access this?**

Comment: `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data); alert(parsedJson[0][0]);` _or_ `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data); alert(parsedJson[0]['0']);`